# "clock skew detected” warning when installing

Tags: linux, makefile

I'm working on a remote machine and while installing a software, I've encountered the "clock skew detected” warning, and whole things fails. I've used the "find . -exec touch {} \;" to update the timestamp of files but it still fails, and more wired, the time stamp is still ahead of real time. Is there any method to let make ignore timestamp? 
[image]

Comment: If you’re doing a clean build and it’s failing then it isn’t because of this. Some other thing must be broken with the build.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify exactly what "working on a remote machine" means, or how you're sharing files between the local and remote systems, but I'll assume that you're using NFS or some other remote partition mounting facility.  In that case nothing you can do on your local system will help.  You have to synchronize the clocks on the local and remote systems.

The timestamps applied to modified files in an NFS share are controlled *by the NFS server*, not by your local system.  So when your local system modifies a file, the modification time is the server's current time not your local system's current time.

If the two systems' clocks are not synchronized, then tools like make which work based on file modification times cannot work properly.